# Remove refids without corresponding id attributes

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to clean up some XML documents and remove all idrefs with no corresponding ids. For whatever reason I'm not getting the syntax in resolving this silly problem. I thought it would be something like this...

```
<xsl:template match="*">
 <xsl:variable name="id_list" select="@id"/>
 <xsl:if test="ref[not(contains($id_list, ./@rid))]">
   <!-- do nothing -->
 </xsl:if>
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

- ref is the element name and @rid is the refid

Sample imput would be something like the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<article>
 <bdy>
  <p>In the second category [<ref rid="bibtts2009060795101" type="bib">2</ref>] and third category [<ref rid="bibtts2009060795102" type="bib">3</ref>]</p>
 </bdy>
 <bib>
  <bb pubtype="article" reftype="nonieee" id="bibtts2009060795101"><au sequence="first"><fnm>T.</fnm><snm>Smith</snm></au></bb>
 </bib>
</article>
```

The second reference `<ref rid="bibtts2009060795102" type="bib">3</ref>` would be removed

Comment: Please, *edit the question, and provide a complete (but small) source XML document. Also indicate which nodes in that document you want removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="id_list" select="@id"/>
```

within the template will set the `$id_list` variable to a node set containing at most one node - the `id` attribute of the (single) element that is the context node in the template.  A better approach might be to define a *key* at the top level of the stylesheet to map each `id` value to its corresponding element(s)

```
<xsl:key name="elementById" match="*[@id]" use="@id" />
```

then given a particular refid value you can quickly determine whether there is any matching `id` using `key('elementById', 'theRefValue')`.  Here is a complete example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="elementById" match="*[@id]" use="@id" />

  <!-- copy everything verbatim by default -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- but ignore all ref elements whose @rid does not
       correspond to any id -->
  <xsl:template match="ref[not(key('elementById', @rid))]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to (a slightly word-wrapped version of) your example document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<article>
 <bdy>
  <p>In the second category [<ref rid="bibtts2009060795101" type="bib">2</ref>]
     and third category [<ref rid="bibtts2009060795102" type="bib">3</ref>]</p>
 </bdy>
 <bib>
  <bb pubtype="article" reftype="nonieee" id="bibtts2009060795101"><au sequence="first"><fnm>T.</fnm><snm>Smith</snm></au></bb>
 </bib>
</article>
```

would produce

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<article>
 <bdy>
  <p>In the second category [<ref rid="bibtts2009060795101" type="bib">2</ref>]
     and third category []</p>
 </bdy>
 <bib>
  <bb pubtype="article" reftype="nonieee" id="bibtts2009060795101"><au sequence="first"><fnm>T.</fnm><snm>Smith</snm></au></bb>
 </bib>
</article>
```

Comment: @user1904476 glad it helped, and welcome to SO.  When you get an answer that solves your problem it's good manners to "accept" it by clicking the tick mark to the left.  If you build up a track record of accepting good answers then people will be more willing to help with your future questions.

Comment: thanks buddy... I clicked it "hope it comes through"... and thanks again for the answer (and the instruction). I really did/do appreciate all the help!